# How can I obtain total cycle time or average cycle time using dataset in Anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

I have the following model where I am using 5 assembler blocks, and as it generates different types of agents at each output the normal work methodology to measure time is not working in this case.

I have been using 5 different datasets, and 5 variables linked with each assembler enter and exit block.

variable1 = time();
dataset1.add(time() - variable1);
....
....
....

And I generating the following time plot chart
[image]

Now, I have been wondering if I could get the total value time chart in one single bar (Bar Chart for each individual dataset).